# How to track the developer who resolved an issue in JIRA

Tags: jira, python-3.7, issue-tracking

I am extracting the information from the JIRA issue tracker. However, the API doesn't seem to record who resolved the issue, i.e., the developer who changed the status from OPEN to RESOLVED. It JUST retrieves the reporter and assignee. Is there any great solution?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a Jira admin change the workflow to record the last user who edited the issue in a user field. This is a bit tedious to maintain
2. Use the REST API and the expand parameter to get the changelog and iterate over it looking for changes in the Resolution or Status. Extract the last user information from that. Also a bit annoying but it does work.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-get-complete-changelog-for-a-issue/qaq-p/501636 and more recent answers